# What is the role of role-attribute in bootstrap dropdowns?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

What does `role="presentation"` do?

I don't see that it makes a change with or without.

Example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" >Dropdown trigger <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: okay... but what it actually does in browsers? any effect at all?

Comment: role=presentation removes the semantics from the element it is on.
http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#use-of-role-presentation